# Get single array from mongoDB collection where the status is current

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[image]

i want to find accepted bodypart which have status active

i tried this

```js
db.patients.find({
    "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z") , 
        "$lt": ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
},
{
    "injury.injurydata.acceptedbodyparts":1,
    "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury":1
    "injury":{ 
        $elemMatch: { 
            "injury.injurydata.acceptedbodyparts.status": "current"
        }
    }
})
```

but still get both array

Comment: Could you post the data inside the acceptedbodyparts array?

Answer (score 0):

Standard projection will not work with nested arrays or limiting any fields inside arrays. For that you need the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.patients.aggregate([
   // First match, Matches documents
   { "$match": {
        "injury.injurydata.injuryinformation.dateofinjury": {
           "$gte": ISODate("2014-05-21T08:00:00Z"), 
           "$lt": ISODate("2014-06-03T08:00:00Z")
        }
   }},

   // Un-wind the arrays
   { "$unwind": "$injury" },

   { "$unwind": "$injury.injurydata" },

   { "$unwind": "$injury.injurydata.acceptedbodyparts" },

   // Now match the required data in the array
   { "$match": {
       "injury.injurydata.acceptedbodyparts.status": "current"
   }},

   // Group only wanted fields
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "acceptedbodyparts": { 
           "$push": "injury.injurydata.acceptedbodyparts"
       }
   }}

])
```

You can add in other fields outside of the array either using [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or by akin g them part of the `_id` in the grouping.

This is just something that is outside of the scope of the standard projection available and the aggregation framework with the extended manipulation capabilities solves this.

Comment: it is giving error Error: Line 9: Unexpected token {

Comment: @MaTya Missing bracket. Amended. Don't just copy and paste as I do not have your data, only a screenshot. Please post data and not screenshots in the future. You should look at some documentation on the aggregation framework and check the field names what you actually have. I can show you the steps but I cannot verify without having your data or at least a sample.

Comment: uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array",
 "code" : 15978,
 "ok" : 0
}     getting this kind of error

Comment: @MaTya Please post a full document with relevant data in you question. It also seems that either field names are incorrect or some fields do not contain arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If `acceptedbodyparts` is an array, you can't query `acceptedbodyparts.status`. If `status` is a field on the documents contained in the array, you would need to use another `$elemMatch` clause in your query. So the last part would look something like this:

```
{"injury":{ "$elemMatch": { "injurydata.acceptedbodyparts": {"$elemMatch": {"status":"current"} }} }}
```

I also removed the `injury.` prefix in the first `$elemMatch` because you're querying data *within* the `injury` array.

Note that this will return the entire document with the full array, as long as it contains the document you're searching for. If your intention is to retrieve a particular element in an array, `$elemMatch` is the wrong approach.